# Orthogonal of an Hilbert subspace and density

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

If $V$ is a subspace of an Hilbert space $H$, I know that the orthogonal of $V$, $V$$^o$, is ($V$closed)$^o$, even if $V$ is not closed.
Does this mean that $V$ is always dense in $V$$^o$?

Thanks!

Comment: It is analogous to the situation in$\mathbb R^2$ where $V$ is a line thru the origin and $V^{\perp}$ is the line  thru the origin, perpendicular to $V$.

Comment: re :your comment on Q 1835519  ... I think your comment is about another Q

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following you here. So let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $V$ a (not necessarily closed) subspace, then $V^{\perp}=\left\{w\in H\mid \left\langle v,w\right\rangle=0 \mbox{ for all }v\in V\right\}$ is the orthogonal complement. Using the continuity of the inner-product you can show that $V^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace of $H$. It follows that $V^{\perp\perp}=\overline{V}$ is the closure of $V$. However $V\cap V^{\perp}=\left\{0\right\}$ for any subspace $V$ of $H$, it follows that $V$ is never dense in $V^{\perp}$.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. So, I meant $V$ dense in $V$$_c$ (i.e $V$ closed) 
  
I am trying to prove $l_1$ is dense in $l_2$ by saying $V$= $l_1$ and bu proving that $V^o$ = $V^o$$_c$ = {0}, but I'm not sure of the conclusion.

Comment: @ Elle. What is $V_c$?... And BTW the standard notation for the orthogonal of $V$ is $V^{\perp}$. ..(V^{\perp} ).

Comment: @Elle. Another thought: Another way to show that $l_1$ is dense in $l_2$ (after showing $l_1\subset l_2)$ is to consider sequences $(x_n)_n$ for which$ \{n: x_n\ne 0\}$ is finite.

Comment: @ user254665 I was oh my phone and couldn't look it up. $V_c$ was meant to be $\bar{V}$. Yes I did that proof, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For *any* subset:
$$A\subseteq\mathcal{H}:\quad A\cap A^\perp=\{0\}$$
As well as it is:
$$A\subseteq\mathcal{H}:\quad\overline{\langle A\rangle}^\perp=A^\perp=\overline{\langle A^\perp\rangle}$$
Moreover it holds:
$$A\subseteq\mathcal{H}:\quad A^{\perp\perp}=\overline{\langle A\rangle}$$

Comment: Thanks.
So if I prove that $l_1$ $=$ $V$ $=$ $\bar{V}$ $^{\perp}$ $=$ {${0}$} I have proved that $\bar{l_1}$ $=$ $\bar{V}$ $=$ $l_2$?
Thanks!

Comment: @Elle you almost got it :) If you can check $\ell_1^\perp=\{0\}$ then it follows $\overline{\ell_1}=\ell_2$. In details: $\overline{\ell_1}=\ell_1^{\perp\perp}=\{0\}^\perp=\ell_2$

Comment: @Elle keep in mind also that it is not $V\subseteq V^\perp$, not $V\supseteq V^\perp$ and thus also not $V=V^\perp$ nor any other variant with $\overline{(\ldots)}$ (unless $\mathcal{H}=\{0\}$). They are in fact even (almost) disjoint: $V\cap V^\perp=\{0\}$

Comment: @Elle My pleasure! :)

Comment: @ Alexander Soz, another question: to prove $l_1$$^{\perp}$ $=$ { $0$ }, is it sufficient to say that <$x$, $y$>= $0$ for all $y$ in $l_1$ implies that $x$ is $0$ (because every $x_n$ is $0$) or should I consider as $x$ the series with only a finite number of elements different from $0$? Thanks for the explanation! :)

Comment: @Elle that is very much correct! Suppose some $x\in\ell_2$ satisfies $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ for all $y\in\ell_1$. Then in particular $x_n=\langle x,e_n\rangle=0$ for all $e_n=(0,\ldots0,1,0,\ldots)$. Thus all $x_n=0$, that is $x=0$. ...

Comment: @Elle ... More generally regard $\mathcal{b}:=\{e_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. There you have $\mathcal{b}^\perp=\{0\}$. Thus you have $\overline{\langle\mathcal{b}\rangle}=\ell_2$. Now note that it was $\ell_0=\langle\mathcal{b}\rangle$ so that $\overline{\ell_0}=\ell_2$. Next note that it was $\ell_0\subseteq\ell_{r\geq1}$ so that also $\overline{\ell_{r\geq1}}=\ell_2$.

Comment: Thank you, so kind of you!! :)

Comment: @Elle You're very much welcome!! :)